# Do I use a graphic card?

Tags: graphics

Weird question... I have a new hardware using kubuntu 18.04

```
$ sudo lspci -v -s 00:02.0
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591c (rev 02)     (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Device 1bab:591c
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

gives me this output. Do I have a graphic card?

I am digging into that because of performance problems with a DisplayLink device.

Edit:

```
$ sudo lspci | grep VGA
```

gives me

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591c (rev 02)
```

Comment: `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` should show both. Your `lspci` is too limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot tell from the output of `sudo lspci -v -s 00:02.0`. Please run `sudo lspci | grep VGA` to get a list of your installed VGA adapters. If the list list contains only Intel, then you only have the onboard Intel graphics card. Else, the list will show you if you also have an Nvidia or AMD card.

Comment: see edit in my question

Comment: According to your edit, you only have an Intel graphics card.

Answer (score 3):

If your computer has a discrete graphics card in addition to the VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device integrated graphics processor `sudo lspci -v` would show all graphics processors in your computer, but sudo `lspci -v -s 00:02.0` might not show it. In order to show all the proprietary drivers that are available to be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories and are compatible with your hardware, open the terminal and type:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Wait at least one minute for the command to scan your computer and generate the list of drivers. The output of this command will be a list of the package names and short descriptions of the available drivers. In addition to showing a list of the available drivers, the above command will often also identify the recommended proprietary driver(s) for your system.

Comment: gives me an empty output

Comment: 1. `sudo lspci -v` should show in a verbose way all graphics processors in your computer. 2. Wait for at least one minute for `ubuntu-drivers devices` to finish processing and return its results in a concise and user friendly format.